# Updating a table from values in an excel file

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a set of excel files with a total of around 130,000 lines. Each line has a column with an ID and a column with a name. I need to update an existing column in one table in the database and fill each ID row with its matching name.

This only needs to be done once so I was going to just use a formula in excel to make each line a query (`=CONCATENATE("UPDATE Table SET Name = '", $C1, "' WHERE ID = ", $A1)`) then copy all of those queries out and run them in Sql Server Management studio. Is this an OK way to do it or will the server choke on 130,000 individual queries?

What is the proper way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Import your Excel workbook to a new table, then join that with your existing table on the ID field and build an update query from that.

Answer (score 0):

Create an SSIS package to import the data. You can have Sql Server create the SSIS package for you by right clicking on the target database name, then select  "Task" from the pop up window, and then select import data. Follow the GUI and in the first window select "Microsoft Excel" as the data source.